# How to Update Android SQLite Database Every 24 Hours?

Tags: android, sqlite, alarmmanager

I am creating an expiry tracking application. In that, I have store the remaining days of an item to get expired. so every day I want to compare the expiry date with the current date and get the difference between them. I want to update the expirydaysleft column in the database with the difference that we found.

Help me with this
want to update the database automatically every 24 hours so that expiry days left can become zero automatically when the expiry date arrives

Comment: If you need do all days an operation and if you need do it in background, then i think that use a WorkManager is a good solution.

Comment: Okayy @ManuelMato i will try it once today lets see if it works good for me or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class

```kotlin
    class UpdateDatabaseWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
        override fun doWork(): Result {
            updateDatabase()
            return Result.success()
        }
    
        private fun updateDatabase() {
            // do the necessary updates here - all the logic needed
        }
    }
```

Then you can call a PeriodicWorkRequest, EG: every 24 hours.

```kotlin
    val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UpdateDatabaseWorker>(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).build()
    
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWorkRequest)
```

In order to stop the execution of periodic work, it needs to be explicitly cancelled:

```kotlin
    WorkManager.getInstance().cancelWorkById(periodicWorkRequest.id)
```